# Merging branches with github

Tags: git, github

I have a branch named `camera-update` and I want the changes made in the branch to go into `master`. I merged into master but should I also merge from `master` into `camera-update` so the changes I make in `master` from that point on will be available in `camera-update`?

Comment: If you want to do that, then yes.

Comment: Yes. Do a fast forward merge (that won't create a commit but put your branch up to date with master)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep `camera-update` then go for it. Merging master in to it and vice versa means that both branches would have the same code. Although I assume if you are merging it in to `master` then you wouldn't want to keep it. In this case you can just delete your local and remote copies of `camera-update`.